# How to use Mongodb if condition in $and operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I am working on MongoDB and next js project. I want to apply filter on products. There are multiple filters.  I want to include a filter in and operator only if value of a variable is not empty or undefined I want something like this that works

```
 Product.find({ 

    $and:[
        { tag : { $in : preferences,},
            {$cond:{
                if: { $ne: ['$allergens'], []],},
                then: { 
                    allergens: {$in :allergens },
                if:{ $ne: ['$type'],''],},
                then: { 
                    type: type ,
               }
            }
})
}]
```

What would be the correct way of doing this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.  The trick is to use `$cond` plus `$ifNull` to see if the field is unset.

```js
var r = [
    { tag: [ "A","B"], allergens: ["pollen","badJokes"], type: "foo" },
    { tag: [ "B","C"], type: "foo" },
    { tag: [ "C","D"], allergens: ["other"] },
    { tag: [ "E","D"], allergens: ["corn"] }
];

db.foo.drop();
db.foo.insert(r);

var tags = [ "C","A" ];
var type = 'foo';
var allergens = ['pollen','corn'];

c = db.foo.aggregate([

    {$match: {$expr: {$and: [
        {$ne:[ [], {$setIntersection: [ "$tag", tags ]} ] },

        {$cond: {
            if: {$eq:["$type", {$ifNull:["$type",null]} ]},
            then: {$eq:["$type",type]},
            else: true
        }},

        {$cond: {
            if: {$eq:["$allergens", {$ifNull:["$allergens",null]} ]},
            then: {$gt:[{$size: {$setIntersection: [ "$allergens", allergens ]}} , 0 ]},
            else: true
        }}
    ]}
             }}
]);
```

Alternatively, it might be easier to construct the `$and` expression programmatically outside of the query:

```js
// Init the and expression array with tags since we always want that:                                                                               
var andExpr = [ {$ne:[ [], {$setIntersection: [ "$tag", tags ]} ] } ];

if(type != undefined) {
    andExpr.push({$eq:["$type",type]});
}
if(allergens != undefined) {
    // Use $ifNull to defend against missing field since
    // $size on a null field will fail, not yield 0:
    andExpr.push({$gt:[{$size: {$setIntersection: [ {$ifNull:["$allergens",[]]}, allergens ]}} , 0 ]});
}

c = db.foo.aggregate([
    {$match: {$expr: {$and: andExpr}} }
]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It was very helpful. Another question. I want to apply check on js variable if its not undefined then include it in query inside $and otherwise dont include it. I dont want it to apply on field in db. Lets say if allergens array is undefined or empty. How will we achieve that? If i want to check if{(allergens.length>0 and allergens!=undefined)},then{ allergens:{
              $in: allergens,
            },}

Comment: Double checking:  if allergens is *not* set outside of the query, then it is ignored in the query, yes?  Meaning it does not matter if the doc contains an allegens field or not?

Comment: @Faiza  Answer expanded above; don't be shy about upvoting and also selecting the answer as the accepted one.

Comment: Thanks it was very helpful. I solved it by adding to object instead of array with Object.assign(andExpr, {
      allergens,
    });

Answer (score 0):

**Check the correct syntax:**

```
{ $and: [ { Expression1 }, { Expression2 }, ..., { ExpressionN } ] }
or
{ { Expression1 }, { Expression2 }, ..., { ExpressionN }}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. It works without if condition but i have difficulty getting it to work with if condition. I want to add filter in $and only if its not empty or undefined.